Cyclotomic polynomial property $\Phi_{p^\alpha}(q) = \Phi_{p^{\alpha-1}}(q^p)$, p prime, $\alpha \geq 2$
I am trying to prove this.
Let $p$ be prime. Verify that, for $\alpha \geq 2$, we have $\Phi_{p^\alpha}(q) = \Phi_{p^{\alpha-1}}(q^p)$. In particular, $\Phi_{p^\alpha}(1) = p$ for any $\alpha \geq 1$.
My try:
I started out with the definition of the cyclotomic polynomial:
$\Phi_{p^{\alpha-1}}(q^p) = \prod_{\substack{1 \leq k < p^{\alpha-1} \\ \gcd(k, p) = 1}} \left( q^p - e^{2 \pi i k / p^{\alpha-1}} \right)$
$\Phi_{p^\alpha}(q) = \prod_{\substack{1 \leq k < p^\alpha \\ \gcd(k, p) = 1}} \left( q - e^{2 \pi i k / p^\alpha} \right)$
I have to show that this expressions are the same, but I don't see any way to transform one into the other, how should I proceed?

Notice that
$$
q^p-e^{2\pi ik/p^{\alpha-1}}=\prod_{0\le r<p}(q-e^{2\pi ik/p^\alpha}e^{2\pi ir/p}),
$$
so we have
$$
\Phi_{p^{\alpha-1}}(q^p)=\prod_{\substack{1\le k<p^{\alpha-1}\\0\le r<p\\p\nmid k}}(q-e^{2\pi i(k+rp^{\alpha-1})/p^\alpha}).
$$
Since the sets
$$
\{k+rp^{\alpha-1}:1\le k<p^{\alpha-1},p\nmid k,0\le r<p\}
$$
and
$$
\{m:1\le m<p^\alpha,p\nmid m\}
$$
are identical, we conclude that $\Phi_{p^{\alpha-1}}(q^p)=\Phi_{p^\alpha}(q)$.

Where did you get the first formula from? And did you do with that to get the second one?

The definition is all I know about cyclotomic polynomials
